# F# Array.choose id equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, linq, f#

I love using Array.choose id in F# on Option[]. What’s the best way to do this in C# for Nullable[]?

--- Edited to address excellent comments ---
In F#, I use `Array.choose id` to filter out `None`: `Option<'T>[] -> 'T []`.
What’s a good way to filter out `null` in C# with Linq: `Nullable<T>[] => T []`?

Comment: you might want to just ask for the equivalent and remove the "best" part. Questions asking for the "best" way to do something tend to get flagged for being opinion-based.

Comment: Is `items.Where(x => x != null)` fine? Are you looking to just get the elements that aren't null, or to also drop from the `Nullable<T>[]` to just `T[]`?

Answer (score 4):

I would translate it into this in C#

```cs
int?[] all = new int?[3] { 10, null, 100 };
int[] chosen = all
    .Where(e => e.HasValue)
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

You can omit `ToArray()` if you just want is as an IEnumerable, and `.Select(..)` if you don't want the nullables unpacked

Comment: I had this except `.Where(e => e != null)`. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` given another function to convert a `T?` into an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToSeq<T>(this T? v) where T : struct
{
    if (v.HasValue)
    {
        yield return v.Value;
    }
}
```

then:

```
var nullables = new int?[] { null, 1, 4, null, 3, null, 29 };
int[] values = nullables.SelectMany(ni => ni.ToSeq()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is clever, but it involves an awful lot of calls to GetEnumerator/MoveNext/Current, since you're creating an IEnumerable per value in the original array. I suspect the Where/Select approach performs better when the array is at all large.

Comment: I wondered about that. On the other hand, this version is safer than the Where / Select (if the order gets flipped => NRE). If C# 8 nullable reference types are on, the lambda in the `Select` becomes `e => e!.Value` which seems unnecessarily dangerous.

Comment: @BrettRowberry Well, the `!` to indicate "I know this isn't null even though the type system says it could be" is exactly made for situations like that where you just checked HasValue and you know for sure it isn't null. Doesn't seem dangerous at all to me, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of the F# Option, you might like the [Optional](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional) library in C#.

In any case, I like using an extension method for this. I use it with that Optional library, but here's a Nullable version. This version is restricted to outputting value types, but the Option version can also handle reference types.

```cs
/// <summary>
///     Allows you to map and filter in a single operation, by passing in a function that returns
///     a Nullable containing the output that should be included in the final result.
///     Only the values that are not null are included in the resulting sequence.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T2> Choose<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> enumerable, Func<T1, T2?> selector) where T2 : struct
{
    if (enumerable is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));
    if (selector is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

    // The nested function ensures argument validation happens immediately, rather than
    // being delayed until the caller starts iterating the results.

    IEnumerable<T2> iterator()
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            var output = selector(item);
            if (output.HasValue)
                yield return output.Value;
        }
    }

    return iterator();
}
```

Comment: The Option type from F# is available in C# as well... Without that 3rd party package

Comment: @MalteR It is, but the Optional library is better suited for use in a language that lacks `match` expressions. It has a `Match` method to which you pass lambda expressions that handle the Some and None case. So unlike using the F# Option from C#, you're prevented from accessing the option's value unless you first check for some/none.